# Difference in Meaning Between "be-," "er-," and "ver-"

Tags: standard-german

Durrell's "Using German" states that a function of the "be-," "er-," and "ver-" prefixes is to give something a certain quality. How do the prefixes differ in this regard? Does it have something to do with the "types" of verbs (ie, those that could theoretically take an "-ig-," umlaut, or nothing at all)? Something along these lines?

"Be-": Used with a noun/adjective, makes a verb with the idea of providing a quality. Sometimes the suffix -ig- is added:

- etw belichten - to expose, to provide with light
- etw bewässern - to irrigate, to provide something with water
- jdn benachtrichtigen - to notify, to provide someone with news

"Er-": with adjectives, has the sense of becoming something or giving something a certain quality. The root vowel often has umlat:

- erblinden - to lose one's sight, to become blind
- erröten - to blush, to become red
- jdn ermuntern - to liven someone up, to make someone cheerful
- etw erwärmen - to heat something, to make something warm

"Ver-": with nouns and adjectives, has the sense of becoming something or giving something a certain quality:

- verarmen - to become poor
- vereinsamen - to become isolated
- etw verlängern - to lengthen something, to make something longer
- jdn versklaven - to enslave somebody, to make someone into a slave

"Ver-": with many nouns, gives the idea of providing with something:

- etw verglasen - to glaze something, to provide with glass
- etw vergolden - to gild something, to provide something with gold
- jdn verwunden - to wound somebody, to provide someone with wounds
- jdn verzaubern - to enchant somebody, to provide somebody with magic

Comment: You should focus on one question at a time. This is basically three in one. The problem is that the choice of prefixes to compare seems arbitrary and could be expanded to the point of becoming **too broad**.

Answer (score 2):

Prefixes have nothing to do with the sound of the word (e.g. Umlaute etc...).

So how to know which to use? Well, there is no answer without many exceptions.

Here's a try (the descriptions you provided are all correct, this is just an addition):

> It depends on the strengh of the action.

Verbs for very soft actions like *begegnen, bewässern, beschwichtigen, benachrichtigen, beheben* do all use the **"be-"** prefix.

**"er-"** is a bit harder to categorize, as there's no clear border.

**"ver-"** however is mostly combined with strong, forceful actions, *verstümmeln, versklaven, vernichten, verletzen, verarmen*. *verglasen* and *vergolden* are obvious exceptions to this.

The "strongest" prefix would be **"zer-"**: *zerstören, zerreißen, zersetzen, zerlegen, zertrampeln* are all very destructive actions.

As said, this is **no general rule** as there are many exceptions, but it is still pretty consistent.

Obvious exceptions: "bekriegen, bekämpfen", "erstürmen", "vergeben, vergolden", "zerreden".

EDIT: For a good explanation for "er-" look at Franks answer. Really good point there.

Comment: Interesting pattern. As you state `no general rule` I keep my exceptions for me :-)

Comment: The same word can have different prefixes which lead to different meanings: "erheben", "beheben", "(sich) verheben" for example.

Answer (score 2):

## Introduction.

The following list is a quick, shortened translation of information found at [dwds.de](https://dwds.de/d/hintergrund), a site of the Berlin-Brandenburg Academy of Sciences and Humanities. Maybe I have mistranslated some of the explanations as I didn't spend the time to examine the exact meaning of each item and search examples. I don't think that all words fit into the pattern, but I think that it should still be useful.

## Meanings:

### zer-

1. expresses that an object becomes something else
2. expresses that an object is dissolved, damaged or destroyed
3. expresses that a promising action is prevented or undone

### be-

1. converts intransitive verbs to transitive verbs
2. makes in combinations with transitive verbs with prepositional object the object an accusative object
3. expresses that a person or thing is furnished with something

### er-

1. expresses that something is successfully completed, leads to the desired result, that an object is obtained or an objective reached

### ver-

1. expresses that a person or thing changes (in the course of time) to someone or something else
2. expresses that a person or thing is made something else, is put in a certain state, transformed into something else
3. expresses that a person or thing is furnished with something
4. expresses that a thing is removed by something (an action), depleted or no longer exists
5. expresses that a person spends his/her time with something
6. expresses that a person is doing something wrong
7. expresses that a thing is impaired by something
8. has the same meaning as the original verb

Answer (score 1):

For all those we can say that the prefix is fossilized in some words, and it's meaning almost opaque, but we can deduce a set of meanings from other examples and the prefixes are productive.

**be-** is comparable to English *be-*, cp. *become*, *bewitched* and roughly denotes direction of activity; cp. *bei*, *by*, Lat. *com* "with", e.g. *correct* -  "berichtigen". Cp. e.g. a neologism from "to twitter", hence * "jemanden betwittern" would be borrowing the semantics of *belabern* (to talk an ear full), or pershaps *behandlend* (to deal with).

**er-** is ... I haven't thought about it before. It's relatively rare, compared to the others. I'd guess that it's akin to *her-*, like *hin-* to *in*; on the model of *erhalten* (cp. syn. *einnehmen*), *ergeben* (cp. syn. *aufgeben*). For *Ergebniss* "result", I would guess, since I don't know any better, that *Ergebnis* is akin to Latin *ergo* (thus, consequently), which is from *ex*+*rego*, of the same root as *rechnen* and *to reckon*; Thus cp. *errechnen*.

**ver-** is a conflation of many different roots, for sure. Which is which is hard to tell for a common native speaker. cp Latin *per*, Ger. *vor*, *für*, and more, note the bunch of translations containing *pro-* below. There's a negative connotation in many words, e.g. *vergebens* "in vein", *verrechnen* "miscalculate", *verführen* "to lure, deceive", etc. but in some words, especially *verletzen* (to hurt, damage) and *verlieren* (to lose, cp. forlorn), *verlassen* "to leave", the negative connotation is already in the stem (all relate to the stem in En. *loss*, *less*), and the common notion of the prefix is mutation, change of state, cp. *perlocate, permutate*, etc. (more or less with a sense *for, towards*).

It also matters what stem the prefix is attached to. With nouns, the meaning is rather clear. "be--en" means the object is acting *onto* something (*benebelt*, foggy mind from smoke), with *er-* I can't think of a single example, and with *ver-* it means to *turn into*, or *apply it to*. The difference is often not clear, as e.g. *golden* (viz *vergolden* "to apply a gold finish") might be adjectival, and *nebeln* verbal, prefix or not. This ambiguity in the suffixes (morphemes are not real suffixes, but oh well) or rather the versatility of the stems may be part of the reason that it works well. On the other hand, we also have *Geltung* "dignity, validity", *Vergeltung* "retaliation" but *gelten* "to be valid", *vergelten* "to retaliate"

### A few examples:

> **suchen** "to seek"
>
> besuchen - to pay a visit (**to** someone)
>
> ersuchen - to seek help (**in**[?] someone)
>
> versuchen - to try out
>
> aussuchen - to pick out, choose
>
> heraussuchen - to find out
>
> ...
>
> *steuern* "to stear", **Steuer** "tax"
>
> **besteuern** - to ask tax, set-up a tax (**for something**)
>
> *versteuern* - to pay tax (**for* something)
>
> **Rechnen** "to calculate" [to sum up, collect, cp. *Rechen* "rake"?]
>
> mostly synonymous *ausrechnen, errechnen, berechnen*, if talking about math homework. The difference is in the inflected forms
>
> *berechnend* - calculating, scheeming [highlights the aim, the subordinate nature of the process; to achieve **by** calculating]
>
> *errechnen* - to calculate a result [chiefly highlights the achievement]
>
> *verrechnen - 1. to count two calculations against each other (e.g. liabilities versus outstanding income with a single partner, also *aufrechnen*, lit. to sum up), 2. to miscalculate [I could see 1 and 2 relate a bit as working untidy instead of "doppelte Buchführung", but deem it unlikely].
>
> *Abrechnung* - billing [*ab* "off"; denotes that the *calculation* the conclusion of a bigger process (of business in most cases]

incidentally, *rechnen*, En. *reckon*, Proto-Germanic *rekanōną "to count, explain", from Proto-Germanic *rekanaz (“swift, ready, prompt”), is from Proto-Indo-European *h₃reǵ-, just as *ergo*, viz *Ergebnis* "Result", *Tag der Abrechnung* "day of reckoning".

> **führen** "to guide, lead"
>
> *hinführen* - lead to
>
> *herführen* - bring here
>
> *entführen* - take away, kidnap; lead astray
>
> verführen - to lure, deceive
>
> befürworten - to concur, endorse, favor, support [this is fossilized, *befür-* exists only in this one idiom, as far as I know, and no analog that the *be-* prefix attaches to is in use, though *Fürwort* could be derived as "endorsement"; A *Führwort could be searched in *Geleitwort*, *Leitwort*, *Vorwort*; Just my two cents]

no *er* + *führen* exists. But we have *Erfahrung* "experience, perception".

> **fahren** "to drive, go"
>
> befahren, die weniger befahrene Straße** - the road less traveled
>
> erfahren - 1. to experience 2. analogue to *erlaufen* "to achieve something by walking the distance"
>
> verfahren - 1. to process, conduct 2. to go the wrong way

The funny bit is, that fahren derives from the *per* root. I'd like to compare *purport*, at another time though.

> **halten** "to hold"
>
> behalten - to keep [to hold **by**; chiefly *behalte bei ...*]
>
> erhalten - to attain [to take **in**]
>
> verhalten - to behave (somehow) ["behave!" would need an object for *verhalte dich ...!* or it would be e.g. *benimm dich* instead, viz *Benehmen*.
>
> **greifen** "to grab, grasp"
>
> begreifen - to take in, understand [cp. Dutch *begripjen*, Ger. *Grips* "smarts"; Ger. *Begriff* "word, meaning"]
>
> ergreifen - to apprehend (a fugitive) [to take them **in**, also *festnehmen, feststellen*, but *fest stellen* also means to *find out a fact*]
>
> ergriffen - moved, taken away
>
> vergreifen - to mistake, to take a wrong (thing, tone "im Ton vergreifen")
>
> vergriffen - out of stock

cp. Gr. grapho "write, sign, draw" for this one.

> **schreiben** "write", *Schrift* "writing"
>
> beschreiben - describe
>
> Einschreiben - a letter send **in**
>
> verschreiben - 1. (med.) to ascribe medication or treatment [lit. to give a receipt for meds] 2. to make a mistake in writing, a typo
>
> verschriftlichen - to set in writing
>
> **tragen** "to carry"
>
> Betragen - behaviour, to carry oneself [possibly calqued of Lat. *cura* "care"?]
>
> Ertrag - yield
>
> Vetrag - contract; vertragen - 1. to get along with each other 2. (col.) to move (a bunch)
>
> vortragen - to perform, to bring before
>
> eintrage - to list, matriculate, to write down into ...
>
> austragen - the delist
>
> Antrag - proposal, request

[again, cp. *Hreg? *ragen*, *hervorragend*, *reach* etc.?]

> **sprechen** "to speak"
>
> *besprechen* - bespeak, negotiate, debate, to go over (this); Besprechung - meeting, critique
>
> *versprechen* - 1. to promise 2. to misspeak
>
> **handeln** "to handle, to act, to deal"
>
> *...*

Comment: Das Verb "steuern" hat mit "Steuern" nicht viel zu tun, höchstens im Sinne von "beisteuern". Es stimmt eben nicht, was die Grünen immer behaupten, und zwar sowohl  etymologisch als auch polit-ökonomisch.

Comment: @Ingo, da bin ich derselben Meinung. Zwar werden die Worte etymologisch verglichen, weshalb ich es auch so aufführe; Immerhin wird eine Steuer, wie auch ein Wagen, (ab)geführt. DWDS bspw. erklärt die Abgabe als "Unterstützung", von "Stütze, Pfahl", und den Lenker als "Steuerruder", "lange Stange zum Staken". Vgl. deshalb auch En. *stake* (bspw. das was beim Pokerspiel in den Pott gelegt wird), *stock market*. de.WT nennt niederdeutsch und mittelniederdeutschen *stouwen* "stehen machen, stellen", als herkunft, vgl. deshalb "bereitstellen, abstellen", etc. und "eine Stange Geld"?

Comment: Do verbs with an “er-“ prefix imply that the action is successful? (ie, do “ersuchen” and “erbitten,” for example, imply that the thing requested was given or gained?) If so, is that also the case for “be-“ and “ver-“?

Comment: I'd say, it implies that the result is final and perpetual:.*belegen* "to occupy; to lay on; etc.", and *verlegen* "to move, displace, loose" (or adj. "shy, embarassed") are reversible actions, but *erlegen* "to kill" (often said of animals "einen Elch erlegen") is not. This is not strict, *zum Erliegen komme* "to come to a stand-still" is not always final, though often it is. Also cp. *Streit beilegen* "to seize a fight", and "Verstorbene beilegen" "to orderly bury the deceased" and *Anhang beilegen* "to add an attachment to a letter*;. *verliegen* negative "to lie resting painfully wrong".

Comment: Comparing *her, hier her*, maybe *ein Tier erlegen* means to score and bring-here a kill (cp. *zur Strecke bringen*, *nederstrecken*, *track record*?). For the perpetual sense, cp. *Ehr-* pertaining to honour, truth, peraps *her-* in *here Ziele*. Indeed, transitive *erzielen* "to gain, win" implies figurative success, as do *erhalten, Erfolg*; Also *Erhalt* may mean perpetual conservation. The archetype for a L1 learner would be *erzählen*, akin "to tell", not sure what that makes.. But cp. further *Erbe, heir, heritage, erteilen, Erbteil, Anteil, orphan, Arbeit*, speculatively.

Comment: Wiktionary says *er-* is from Proto Germanic \*uz "out, up", whence also "ur-" (in *Urvater, Ursuppe*)?! I can hardly tell how to derive this from that, so I'm not sure how much it helps. Cp. *auf* "up, on", *aufzählen* "ennumerate" (vs *erzählen* "to recount" etc), *aufgießen* "to fill up" (vs *ergießen*, the act that leads to *Erguss* "the result of something that flowed together", often said of erratic writing like mine, also *Bluterguss* "haematom"; note that pouring as in libation or rain may have ritualistic connotations), *aufleben* "to live up, sprout" (vs *erleben* "experience"), etc.

Comment: Also cp. passiv *Urteil ergeht*, akt. *Urteil fällen*. Cp. *jud-* and the like (judge, justice, jury), *aufrichtig* "upright [morally]*, and PIE \*Hreg- et al, whence "rex, right, correct", etc., and PIE \*reg-, \*red- et al, whence at least some terms that are directly related to being upright or strong. *aussprechen* "pronounce, declare*, *Aussprache* "consolidation, agreement, ...", *Absprache*, ... *ein Urteil aussprechen, verkünden* ... *austeilen* "to deal out", *Titel* "title, privilege, impartedm quittance" (cp. *to be entitled to*). I'm tired.